# Questions about RDMA tunneled atomics

Tags: rdma

I am currently reading the RDMA development manual and I found an advanced feature called TUNNELED ATOMICS: https://docs.nvidia.com/networking/display/rdmacore50/tunneled+atomic. However, I found the explanation on this website to be vague and hard to understand. And there seems to be no detailed information about this feature on the internet.

I wonder if anyone could provide more detailed information about this operation?

Comment: [Tunneled Atomic](https://docs.nvidia.com/networking/display/mlnxofedv461000/optimized+memory+access#src-12013520_OptimizedMemoryAccess-TunneledAtomic) has a bit more information, including how to verify if the feature is enabled on your device. The mention of ``IBV_EXP_ACCESS_TUNNELED_ATOMIC`` and ``ibv_exp_reg_mr`` suggest an _experimental_ new feature. My initial thought is that Nvidia have added a new feature which is currently only supported in their MLNX_OFED distribution, and isn't yet in the mainline Kernel nor https://github.com/linux-rdma/rdma-core.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. This document does provide more information. It says one can "encapsulate the tunneled atomic commands in the send buffer". However, I'm confused about how to "encapsulate". By the way, is "tunneled atomic" a terminology specific to computer science? I've never heard about this before and could not understand what this means.

Answer (score 0):

This answer records an investigation in trying to understand what the *Tunneled Atomic* operation does.

Downloaded `MLNX_OFED_SRC-4.9-7.1.0.0.tgz` from [Linux Drivers](https://network.nvidia.com/products/infiniband-drivers/linux/mlnx_ofed/), which are the sources from the NVIDIA *MLNX_OFED Download Center*. Manually unpacked some of the `SRPMS` source RPMs to look at the code and supporting comments.

`libibverbs-41mlnx1-OFED.4.9.3.0.0.49710.src.rpm` which contains the source for the user space `ibverbs` library has:

1. The C source code has `IBV_EXP_ACCESS_TUNNELED_ATOMIC`, `IBV_EXP_DEVICE_ATTR_TUNNELED_ATOMIC`, `IBV_EXP_TUNNELED_ATOMIC_SUPPORTED` and `tunneled_atomic_caps`. However, are unable to find any comments explaining what they do.
2. `man/ibv_exp_reg_mr.3` which is the source for the man page for the  `ibv_exp_reg_mr` function:

   > if **IBV_EXP_ACCESS_TUNNELED_ATOMIC** is set, part of the MSB's of the address is set to a predefined value in order to generate a command in the CPU and do atomic for RDMA WR operations in the memory controller instead of accessing the user's memory (DMA). That is saying **IBV_EXP_ACCESS_REMOTE_WRITE** must be set as well to support this opration from remote side. This operation is only eligible when tunneled_atomic_caps from ibv_exp_query_device has bit mask IBV_EXP_TUNNELED_ATOMIC_SUPPORTED set.

   Where the above is a bit more information that in [Tunneled Atomic](https://docs.nvidia.com/networking/display/mlnxofedv461000/optimized+memory+access#src-12013520_OptimizedMemoryAccess-TunneledAtomic) in the online OFED documentation.

`mlnx-ofa_kernel-4.9-OFED.4.9.7.1.0.1.src.rpm` contains the source for the OFED Kernel drivers. They contains references to tunneled atomics, but again can't seem to find any comments explaining what they do.

The Kernel source file has the following `mlnx-ofa_kernel-4.9/drivers/net/ethernet/mellanox/mlx5/core/main.c`, which is the only call to `set_tunneled_operation`:

```
#ifdef HAVE_PNV_PCI_AS_NOTIFY
static void mlx5_as_notify_init(struct mlx5_core_dev *dev)
{
    struct pci_dev *pdev = dev->pdev;
    u32 log_response_bar_size;
    u64 response_bar_address;
    u64 asn_match_value;
    int err;

    if (!mlx5_core_is_pf(dev))
        return;

    if (!MLX5_CAP_GEN(dev, tunneled_atomic) &&
        !MLX5_CAP_GEN(dev, as_notify))
        return;

    err = pnv_pci_enable_tunnel(pdev, &asn_match_value);
    if (err)
        return;

    err = set_tunneled_operation(dev, 0xFFFF, asn_match_value, &log_response_bar_size, &response_bar_address);
    if (err)
        return;

    if (!MLX5_CAP_GEN(dev, as_notify))
        return;

    err = pnv_pci_set_tunnel_bar(pdev, response_bar_address, 1);
    if (err)
        return;

    dev->as_notify.response_bar_address = response_bar_address;
    dev->as_notify.enabled = true;
    mlx5_core_dbg(dev,
              "asn_match_value=%llx, log_response_bar_size=%x, response_bar_address=%llx\n",
              asn_match_value, log_response_bar_size, response_bar_address);
}
#endif
```

Where the above function which references tunneled atomics and tunneled operation is inside conditional compilation on `HAVE_PNV_PCI_AS_NOTIFY` being defined. Looking at the build scripts `HAVE_PNV_PCI_AS_NOTIFY` is only defined when the function `pnv_pci_enable_tunnel` is present in `asm/pnv-pci.h` which is an include file inside `/arch/powerpc/include`. I.e. specific to the PowerPC architecture. On searching think `pnv_pci_enable_tunnel` is used to support the [Coherent Accelerator Processor Interface (CAPI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_Accelerator_Processor_Interface) on IBM's Power8 processors.

### Summary

I haven't specifically answered the question of what the RDMA tunneled atomics do, but could be for use with CAPI, which itself is used in large data center computers.